# Canvas drawing multiple lines instead of one javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

So I want user to be able to draw line, I want it something like this,

[image]

But I also want him to draw multiple lines separated so I removed this line:

```
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

But when I do that I got this

[image: https://prnt.sc/vp8amp]

Here is my code:

```js
//Canvas
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//constiables
// const canvasx = $(canvas).offset().left;
// const canvasy = $(canvas).offset().top;
let canvasx = canvas.offsetLeft;
let canvasy = canvas.offsetTop;
let last_mousex = (last_mousey = 0);
let mousex = (mousey = 0);
let mousedown = false;

//Mousedown
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
  last_mousex = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasx);
  last_mousey = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasy);
  mousedown = true;
});

//Mouseup
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
  mousedown = false;
});

//Mousemove
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  mousex = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasx);
  mousey = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasy);
  if (mousedown) {
    // ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(last_mousex, last_mousey);
    ctx.lineTo(mousex, mousey);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  //Output
  document.querySelector("#output").innerHTML =
    "current: " +
    mousex +
    ", " +
    mousey +
    "<br/>last: " +
    last_mousex +
    ", " +
    last_mousey +
    "<br/>mousedown: " +
    mousedown;
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: `let mousex = (mousey = 0);` declares **one** variable, `mousex`. The other symbol, `mousey`, will be an implicit global variable. You need `let mousex = 0, mousey = 0;`

Comment: @Pointy I changed it in code but when I draw nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want correctly, this is because you are setting the last_mousex and last_mousey ONLY when the user presses down.

You do not update it every time they move, so the moment they click the "origin" is locked to that position. And then is never updated in sequential draws.

To fix this just move the last_mouseX/Y from here

```
//Mousedown
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
  last_mousex = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasx); // remove this 
  last_mousey = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasy); // and this
  mousedown = true;
});
```

to right after where you render the line:

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  mousex = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasx);
  mousey = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasy);
  if (mousedown) {
    // ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(last_mousex, last_mousey);
    ctx.lineTo(mousex, mousey);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  //right here! 
  last_mousex = parseInt(e.clientX - canvasx);
  last_mousey = parseInt(e.clientY - canvasy);
```

[image]

Comment: It actually worked! But now when I draw I got this crooked lines https://prnt.sc/vp8ms0 But what I want is nice line that is straight.

Comment: I'm not sure what might cause that. Crooked lines couldn't come from the code... Maybe check your mouse? Lol

Comment: Just making sure.. your canvas has width and height that line up with the css right?

Comment: In css I have `canvas {
  cursor: crosshair;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
` And in html `<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>`

Comment: Okay so here is what you can do, I cannot replicate this issue. However if you want to create a canvas anybody can draw on, it might be worth adding a "smoother" function anyway. I don't have much time right now, but an easy patch to fix jitter could be only drawing if the distance between the current position, and the previous, is greater than your "average" buffer (like 10 or something). So only draw if the line is greater than 10 pixels long. This way you won't end up with tiny vibrations in your line due to hardware.

Comment: Something like this: 
```if (mousedown && distance(mousex, mousey, last_mousex, last_mousey) > 10) { ... draw line and update last_mousePosition```

Comment: here's a distance function for you too: 
```const distance = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => {
    return Math.sqrt(((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)) + ((y2-y1)*(y2-y1)));
}```